# unable to pass jQuery .val() into fullCalendar json data function

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I'm trying to pass a value, attained from jQuery $('#user-selector').val()

as a parameter into fullCalendar json data function, but for whatever reason, it will not post the value, it's simply blank. When I console log the value, it does contain what it should...

```
$("select#user-selector").on('change',function(){

    console.log($('#user-selector').val());

    $('#calendar').fullCalendar('refetchEvents');
});


$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
defaultDate: getCurrentDate(), 
    editable: true,
    //events: 
    events: {
        url: 'php/event_handler.php', 
        type: 'GET',
        data: {
            user_id: $('#user-selector').val()
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Unable to load the requested events, please refresh and try again!');
    }
},
```

Comment: can you post your php/event_handler.php file's code too?

Answer (score 0):

`user_id: $('#user-selector').val()` is evaluated only once (at `document.Ready` I'm guessing) and does not constitute a binding.

Here is what you could do :

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            defaultDate: getCurrentDate(), 
            editable: true,
            //events: 
            events: {
                url: 'php/event_handler.php', 
                type: 'GET',
                data: function() {
                        return {
                            user_id: $('#user-selector').val()
                    };
                },
                error: function() {
                    alert('Unable to load the requested events, please refresh and try again!');
                }
            }
```